# LinkedIn keeps suggesting connection on Login even though I rejected them

Tags: linkedin

Whenever I go onto LinkedIn (or, almost every time), I get a screen saying:

> A LinkedIn connection means you’ll never lose touch
>   Invite your contacts onto LinkedIn to keep up with their careers.
>   If someone you invite doesn’t respond right away, we’ll send up to two 
>   reminders.

I don't want to invite my contacts onto Linked-In. In fact, I don't even know where LinkedIn gets these addresses from - I haven't shared any contacts with them that I can remember. If I "Skip" - the same screen will come up after a few more days when I get on LinkedIn again.

How do I make this go away permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I found the following, but have not had a chance to test it as it didn't happen at every logon.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/43377

> **Deleting Imported Contacts from LinkedIn**
>
> You can delete any of the
>   contacts you've imported to the [LinkedIn Contacts Manager](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/91972) address
>   book from the [Manage your contacts](https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/contacts/imported/) page.
>
> To delete an imported contact from LinkedIn Contacts Manager:
>
> 1. Click the  **My Network** icon at the top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> 2. Click **See all** below **Your connections** on the left rail.
> 3. Click **Manage synced and imported contacts** near the top right of the page.
> 4. Click the **Imported** tab at the top of the **Manage your contacts** page.
> 5. Select the box next to the contact you want to delete.
>
>    - You can also select the box next to **Select all** to delete all contacts at once.
> 6. Click the **Delete selected** button near the top of the page.
> 7. Click **Delete selected contact** in the confirmation pop-up window.
>
> If invitations were sent to the contacts imported from your address
>   book by mistake, you can [withdraw the invitations](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/62008).
>
> **Note**: If you see an **Imported Contacts** section on the [Contacts](https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/contacts/imported/) page under **Source**, these are 1st-degree connections
>   whose contact information was manually edited before switching to the
>   new Contacts.
>
> Learn more about [importing and inviting your email contacts.](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4214)

Comment: On StackExchange sites,answers should include the relevant solution directly rather than merely a link. Perhaps this is why someone downvoted your answer. But I think this should indeed work so +1.